# XML Parser related questions in Objective C - help needed

Tags: objective-c, xml-parsing

I knew, my questions may create some angry on me. But, I have no other way to know the things that happens around me.

Actually, I'm working on a well-written Objective C code. The code uses parser to parse the XML file that comes from the server. When I try to understand about parser and about its functionality, lots of confusion I'm getting :(

- How many parsers that we have in Cocoa framework? (Using appropriate parser is not my indent)
- How can I find which parser is used in my app?

  In my app, they defined one variable in .h file. That is,

  `xmlParserCtxtPtr context;`

  Some functions are defined in .m file. They are,

  `static void startElementSAX(...);`

  `static void endElementSAX(...);`

  `static void charactersFoundSAX(...);`

  `static void errorEncounteredSAX(...);`

  `static xmlSAXHandler simpleSAXHandlerStruct;`

  And they imported `<libxml/tree.h>`.

  Here, which parser did they use?
- My last question is a FAQ only. The best & beautiful way to learn new things is by practice. But still, I can not find a smart sample that demonstrates the parsers separately with explanation. (Also, I can not find any sample that parsers a local xml file that stored in my PC.)

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- How many parsers that we have in Cocoa framework?
  To answer your first question, there is a number of different xml-parsers available. I suggest [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project) reading to choose one that is suitable for your specific problem.
- How can I find which parser is used in my app?
  You have already written the answer to this question. You are using the xmlParserCtxtPtr - parser.

To load a local xml file you use

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Songbook" ofType:@"xml"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
```

and then you initialize your xmlParser with an URL. Hope it helps even though it might be a bit late...